# How to include composer local path with versions

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to include local repository with versions. I have following folder structure.

```
+myapp
-composer.json
+libs
--lib1
---composer.json
--lib2
---composer.json
```

I need to add different version of lib1 and lib2 to include in myapp composer.json file. How could I add version information to composer local repositories?

Comment: I guess it supports only one version, see the related post here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150695/how-does-composer-handle-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `version` into `composer.json` files of these libraries. For example:

`libs/lib1/composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "me/lib1",
    "version": "1.2.2",
    ...
```

`libs/lib2/composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "me/lib2",
    "version": "1.3.2",
    ...
```

Then explicitly update these libraries:

```
composer update me/lib1
composer update me/lib2
```

Declared versions should be saved into `composer.lock` and `installed.json`.