# Problem installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 league/flysystem ^2.0 required but stuck at 1.1.3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, flysystem

I am attempting to install league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 with laravel but receive the following:

```
Problem 1
- The requested package league/flysystem (locked at 1.1.3, required as ^2.0) is satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
 Problem 2
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.28.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.4
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-RC1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-beta.3
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-beta.2
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-beta.1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.4
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.2
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.28.4, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.4].
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1
- laravel/framework v7.28.4 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.34 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.x-dev, 1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for league/flysystem ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0-alpha.1, 2.0.0-alpha.2, 2.0.0-alpha.3, 2.0.0-alpha.4, 2.0.0-beta.1, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.0-beta.3, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.x-dev].
```

When I try to update league/flysystem I receive the following:

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.28.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.4
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-RC1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-beta.3
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-beta.2
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-beta.1
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.4
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.2
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.28.4, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.
- Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1
- laravel/framework v7.28.4 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.34 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.x-dev, 1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: league/flysystem[2.x-dev, 1.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for league/flysystem ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0-alpha.1, 2.0.0-alp
```

I am also unable to remove league/flysystem or update laravel

Comment: It's already installed with Laravel, but you're trying to install a newer version, as the error clearly states. `laravel/framework v7.28.4 requires league/flysystem ^1.0.34`

Answer (score 3):

You're using Laravel 7 (although the same is true for Laravel 8), if you take a look at the [`laravel/framework` `composer.json` file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/composer.json#L26), you will see that it is requiring version 1; `"league/flysystem": "^1.1"`

Per composer constraints, this will allow any version from 1.1 to less than 2 (`>=1.1 <2`).

Now it is *technically* possible to install 2 different versions of a package, but I'd highly advise against it as you have to monkey with the autoloader to change the namespace for one version of the package. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150695/how-does-composer-handle-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package) covers the details on how to do it **if you absolutely must**.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using laravel/framework version >= 8. Try running this command in your console. It worked for me.

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.